# how to make focus event on a-entity AFRAME?

Tags: events, event-handling, aframe

i have a entity text and and side by side have event click, but when i click on the right, left event was listen and then just going to right event ?

it seems like the trigger on left must pass on the right then going to left

example

button 1 : going to '/createroom'
button 2: going to '/joingroom'

when i click button2 : it was trigger to '/createroom' then going to '/joinroom'

is that because of the width a-entity text ? or what ??

this is my a-entity

```
<a-text
  id="createRoom"
  cursor="rayOrigin: mouse;maxDistance: 30; fuse: true ; far: 10"
  width="10"
  position="-6 3 -5"
  align="left"
  value="create room"
  geometry="primitive:plane"
  animation="property: position; from: -6 3 -5; to: -6 3.5 -5; loop: true; dir: alternate; easing:linear;dur:1000"
>
</a-text>

 // buton2
<a-text
  id="joinRoom"
  width="10"
  align="right"
  raycaster="objects: .collidable; far: 8"
  position="6 0.7 -5"
  cursor="rayOrigin: mouse;maxDistance: 30; fuse: true"
  value="joinroom"
  geometry="primitive:plane"
  animation="property: position; from: 6 0.7 -5; to: 6 0.9 -5; loop: true; dir: alternate; easing:linear;dur:1000"
></a-text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the `cursor` component either:

- on the scene: `<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">`
- on any element which is the starting point of the ray:

  ```
  <a-camera>
    <a-entity cursor></a-entity>
  </a-camera>

  <a-entity id="vive-controller" cursor></a-entity>
  ```

Otherwise the rays may get through many "bystanding" entities, and result in multiple `click` events.

Correctly working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/39nebs12/3/). 
Fiddle with cursors on the texts (like in the question) [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/39nebs12/5/).